# MVC - Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository

In our MVC implementaton,
we have a View, Controller and a Model

The Model is an .edmx file (Entity Framework).

Our controller calls a Repository where we do get the data from the Entity Framework.

Is the Repository considered part of the Model then? 
Is it usually part of the Model as the M is MVC can be many layers.

Comment: More or less, yes.  The repository will be outside of the UI, or presentation layer, while both the Controllers and the Views will be inside the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository is not part of the Model, it is it's own separate entity that can also be invoked at the Controller and/or Model level when needed. The repository is simply an area of storage, i.e. a database.

As a breakdown:

- The controller takes care of all the web requests, i.e. `GET` and `POST`. It can also populate a model and return the appropriate view for that request.
- The model contains the domain objects and logic to perform (i.e. extracting information from the repository and manipulating the data to be passed to the view).
- The view returns the markup which is based upon the data stored within the model.

In certain implementations additional logic such as checking conditions and Repository calls also take place at the controller level, which is a technique known as Fat Controller Thin Model.